# How to retain good records when inserting from stored procedure and still catch the error message?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, error-handling

I am trying to catch the error message when inserting records into a temp table from a stored procedure without rolling back everything.  To illustrate, here is what I am trying to do:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMPTABLE (some fields....)

BEGIN TRY
     INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE
     EXEC SomeStoredProcedure @param1, @param2
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
     ' Log error message in here
END CATCH
```

When executing just the `INSERT INTO` statement outside of a try catch block from within SSMS, I get a message similar to the following:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Procedure SomeStoredProcedure, Line 337
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
>   The statement has been terminated.

BUT..., I also get some records inserted into `#TEMPTABLE` (perfectly fine for my requirements since I can't modify the existing SP but it still returns the data needed).

If I use the try catch block, I can capture the error message but `#TEMPTABLE` is empty.

Is there a way to capture the error message but still retain the records in `#TEMPTABLE`?

Honestly, I don't really need the try catch but this behavior got me curious.

---

Here is a sample code to reproduce the behavior I am experiencing:

```
-- SomeProc declaration 
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SomeProc] AS BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(ID INT NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(1 / 0)

SELECT ID FROM #TEMP END
GO
```

The following won't insert any records on #TEMPTABLE but will return error number

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMPTABLE(ID INT NOT NULL)

BEGIN TRY

INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE
EXEC dbo.SomeProc END TRY BEGIN CATCH
SELECT @@ERROR END CATCH

SELECT * FROM #TEMPTABLE

DROP TABLE #TEMPTABLE
```

The following will insert a record on #TEMPTABLE but will not return any error number

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMPTABLE(ID INT NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE EXEC dbo.SomeProc

SELECT @@ERROR  -- returns 0

SELECT * FROM #TEMPTABLE

DROP TABLE #TEMPTABLE
```

Comment: Does SomeStoredProcedure return multiple result sets?   In general, I avoid writing code that generates "expected errors" and simply discards them. Handling/preventing the errors upstream is generally the best way to handle that.

Comment: If error indicates that statement is terminated then nothing should be inserted in #temptable, unless you are doing multiple inserts.

Comment: @MaxVernon Ah, I missed that bit. Seems my critical reading skills are lacking today. Still curious if the proc returns multiple result sets--which might at least explain why some results land in the #temptable in some scenarios

Comment: @AMtwo - resolved by checking the docs for `TRY...CATCH` - see my answer below.  I'm removing my comments above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TRY...CATCH` block is causing the execution of the stored procedure to terminate before it has a chance to return the values in #TEMP.

Try this stored proc:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.SomeProc') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.SomeProc;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SomeProc]
AS 
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #TEMP
    (
        ID INT NOT NULL
    );

    INSERT INTO #TEMP 
    VALUES (1);

    INSERT INTO #TEMP 
    VALUES (1/0);

    PRINT (N'Run the SELECT');

    SELECT ID 
    FROM #TEMP;
END
GO
```

Running it, like this, without a `TRY...CATCH`, allows all the statements in the proc to run:

```
EXEC dbo.SomeProc;
```

The output:

> Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SomeProc, Line 12
>   Divide by zero error encountered.
>   The statement has been terminated.
>   Run the SELECT

However, if you run it inside a `TRY...CATCH`:

```
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC dbo.SomeProc;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT (ERROR_MESSAGE());
END CATCH
```

You see only the error message:

> Divide by zero error encountered.

The `PRINT (N'Run the SELECT');` never runs, and indeed the `SELECT ID FROM #TEMP;` never runs either.  Hence no rows are returned, and nothing can be inserted into your `#TEMPTABLE`

From the [MSDN documentation on TRY...CATCH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx#Anchor_2):

> If there is an error in the code that is enclosed in a TRY block, control passes to the first statement in the associated CATCH block.

As always, the devil is in the details.  `TRY...CATCH` always aborts the code inside the `BEGIN TRY...END TRY` code block if any error over severity 10 occurs that does not close the database connection.  Execution is immediately passed into the `BEGIN CATCH...END CATCH` block, even if this means aborting code in a stored proc.

Be aware that if an error occurs on any row the entire insert will not happen. The only reason you're seeing this error, and a row being inserted, is because you have two insert statements, one that runs to completion, and one that throws an error.  Take for instance:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.SomeProc') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.SomeProc;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SomeProc]
AS 
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #TEMP
    (
        ID INT NOT NULL
    );

    INSERT INTO #TEMP 
    VALUES (1);

    INSERT INTO #TEMP 
    VALUES (1)
        , (2)
        , (3)
        , (4)
        , (1/0);

    PRINT (N'Run the SELECT');

    SELECT ID 
    FROM #TEMP;
END
GO
```

Using this stored proc, either inside a `TRY...CATCH` or with no `TRY...CATCH` block, will only result in a single row being inserted into the `#TEMPTABLE` - none of the rows in the 2nd insert will be present in the output.

Comment: Hi Max, try changing your SP to something like this: CREATE TABLE #TEMP(ID INT NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES( 1 /0)

SELECT * FROM #TEMP

Comment: @tariktik - I've updated my answer to show why you are seeing the unexpected results.

Comment: As a follow-up to the question, is there a way to retrieve both the result and error message?

Comment: You'd need to modify the stored procedure to capture `@@ERROR` after each statement, and not use a `TRY...CATCH` construct.

Comment: also, be aware that if an error occurs on *any row* the entire insert will not happen.  The only reason you're seeing this error, and a row being inserted, is because you have two insert statements, one that runs to completion, and one that throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the error without catching it by using `@@ERROR` and then looking up the error message in `sys.messages`.

```
DECLARE @error int

INSERT...

SET @error = @@ERROR

SELECT [text]
FROM sys.messages
WHERE message_id = @error AND language_id = 1033
```

Comment: Thanks Tara. I tried but @@ERROR does not return anything since the error is from within another stored procedure